# Substitute symbols with values and simplify equations in R

Tags: r, symbolic-math

I would like to substitute symbols in equation as well as simplify equations in R.

data:

```
num_names <- c("num_a","num_aa","num_aaa","num_b")
num_values <- c(1,2,3,4)

df <- data.frame(id=c(1:3),
                 equation=c("2*x_a*num_a","num_a*(num_aa+1)^2","num_aaa+num_b*x_b"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

df

  id           equation
1  1        2*x_a*num_a
2  2 num_a*(num_aa+1)^2
3  3  num_aaa+num_b*x_b
```

expected output:

```
  id equation
1  1    2*x_a
2  2        9
3  3  3+4*x_b
```

Comment: I don't know if dataframes are the best tool for what you're looking for, if you have to constantly access numbers from other rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```r
df$eqn2 <- Reduce(function(prev, this) gsub(paste0("\\b", num_names[this], "\\b"), num_values[this], prev),
                  seq_along(num_names), init = df$equation)
df$eqn2 <- sapply(df$eqn2, function(eq) if (grepl("[A-Za-z_]", eq)) eq else eval(parse(text = eq)))
df$eqn2 <- gsub("(\\b1\\*|\\*1\\b)", "", df$eqn2)
df
#   id           equation    eqn2
# 1  1        2*x_a*num_a   2*x_a
# 2  2 num_a*(num_aa+1)^2       9
# 3  3  num_aaa+num_b*x_b 3+4*x_b
```

Not the most elegant, but it works well-enough here.

One problem with doing this perfectly symbolically is that some objects exist (as referenced by the `num_*` variables, not the preferred format for true symbolic lookup) and some do not. I don't know of a way to evaluate only part of the equations without running into "not found" errors.

Comment: Thank you, this works really well! Technically, this doesn't do the simplify part but that is just for bonus :-)

Answer (score 2):

We use the polynom package to convert the string to a polynomial class object and then a string.  `e` is the equation converted to an R expression and `L` is a list of the values of the variables with names being the names of the variables.  We also include `polynomial()` with name held in `xname` (which is the only undefined variable in `e` or `dummy` if none) into `L`. Then evaluate `e` with respect to `L` and convert it to character.  `polynomial` always results in the name `x` so at the end we replace `x` with `xname`.

```
library(polynom)

transform(df, equation = sapply(equation, function(ch) {
   e <- str2lang(ch)
   L <- c(list(polynomial()), as.list(num_values))
   xname <- setdiff(all.vars(e), num_names)
   if (length(xname) == 0) xname <- "dummy"
   names(L) <- c(xname, num_names)
   gsub("x", xname, as.character(eval(e, L)))
}))
```

giving

```
  id  equation
1  1     2*x_a
2  2         9
3  3 3 + 4*x_b
```

Comment: Thanks! I will look into the package.